# ASP.net web service and Web Api in a single port

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I already have a webservice which is running on a port, and we are going to implement another webapi project which need to be hosted on the same server without opening a new port. Is there any way to achieve that???

Comment: Are you hosting in IIS, or using OWIN self-hosting, or what? If IIS, can you just use a different virtual directory, or even a different hostname?

Comment: IIS thank you Ross

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possibilities:

- Run the WebAPI in a virtual directory of the same site.
- Run the WebAPI as a new site on the same port but with a different hostname binding. Requires a new DNS entry and (if using https) a new certificate (or a wildcard certificate).